# When i try to load base64 image using flame engine at that time i got below error. i used flame: ^0.27.0

Tags: flutter, dart, flame

when I used aync await method at that time it works properly but when i try to load image in flame's component class I got error:

[image]

I have created a Background class that extends flame engine's component class. Now I am tring to load a base64 image using the `then` function, but I get an error but when I use the async `await` method for image loading it  works properly.

```
class Background extends Component with Resizable {
    static final Paint _paint = Paint();
    Size imageSize = Size(411.42857142857144, 822.8571428571429);

    @override
    void render(Canvas c) {
        Rect myRect = const Offset(0.0, 0.0) & Size(size.width, size.height);
        Flame.images.fromBase64('demo', imageBase).then((value) {
        paintImage(canvas: c, rect: myRect, image: value);
    });
}

@override
void update(double t) {
// TODO: implement update
}



void paintImage({
    @required Canvas canvas,
    @required Rect rect,
    @required image.Image image,
    String debugImageLabel,
    double scale = 1.0,
    ColorFilter colorFilter,
    BoxFit fit,
    Alignment alignment = Alignment.center,
    Rect centerSlice,
    ImageRepeat repeat = ImageRepeat.noRepeat,
    bool flipHorizontally = false,
    bool invertColors = false,
    FilterQuality filterQuality = FilterQuality.low,
    bool isAntiAlias = false,
}) {
    if (rect.isEmpty) return;
    Size outputSize = rect.size;
    Size inputSize = Size(image.width.toDouble(), image.height.toDouble());
    Offset sliceBorder;
    if (centerSlice != null) {
        sliceBorder = Offset(
        centerSlice.left + inputSize.width - centerSlice.right,
        centerSlice.top + inputSize.height - centerSlice.bottom,
    );
    outputSize = outputSize - sliceBorder as Size;
    inputSize = inputSize - sliceBorder as Size;
    }
    fit ??= centerSlice == null ? BoxFit.scaleDown : BoxFit.fill;
    assert(centerSlice == null || (fit != BoxFit.none && fit != BoxFit.cover));
    final FittedSizes fittedSizes =
    applyBoxFit(fit, inputSize / scale, outputSize);
    final Size sourceSize = fittedSizes.source * scale;
    Size destinationSize = fittedSizes.destination;
    if (centerSlice != null) {
        outputSize += sliceBorder;
        destinationSize += sliceBorder;
    }
// Output size is fully calculated.

    if (repeat != ImageRepeat.noRepeat && destinationSize == outputSize) {
        repeat = ImageRepeat.noRepeat;
    }
    final Paint paint = Paint()..isAntiAlias = isAntiAlias;
    if (colorFilter != null) paint.colorFilter = colorFilter;
    if (sourceSize != destinationSize) {
        paint.filterQuality = filterQuality;
    }
    paint.invertColors = invertColors;
    final double halfWidthDelta =
        (outputSize.width - destinationSize.width) / 2.0;
    final double halfHeightDelta =
        (outputSize.height - destinationSize.height) / 2.0;
    final double dx = halfWidthDelta +
        (flipHorizontally ? -alignment.x : alignment.x) * halfWidthDelta;
    final double dy = halfHeightDelta + alignment.y * halfHeightDelta;
    final Offset destinationPosition = rect.topLeft.translate(dx, dy);
    final Rect destinationRect = destinationPosition & destinationSize;
    final bool needSave = repeat != ImageRepeat.noRepeat || flipHorizontally;
    if (needSave) canvas.save();
    if (repeat != ImageRepeat.noRepeat) canvas.clipRect(rect);
    if (flipHorizontally) {
    final double dx = -(rect.left + rect.width / 2.0);
    canvas.translate(-dx, 0.0);
    canvas.scale(-1.0, 1.0);
    canvas.translate(dx, 0.0);
    }
    if (centerSlice == null) {
    final Rect sourceRect = alignment.inscribe(
        sourceSize,
        Offset.zero & inputSize,
    );
    if (repeat == ImageRepeat.noRepeat) {
        canvas.drawImageRect(image, sourceRect, destinationRect, paint);
    } else {
        print("no repet else");
    }
    }
//if (needSave) canvas.restore();
    }
}
```

Comment: Which flutter version are you using?

Answer (score 2):

This is totally not acceptable:

```dart
    @override
    void render(Canvas c) {
        Rect myRect = const Offset(0.0, 0.0) & Size(size.width, size.height);
        Flame.images.fromBase64('demo', imageBase).then((value) {
            paintImage(canvas: c, rect: myRect, image: value);
        });
    }
```

The render method must be **sync**. It takes a canvas object to be rendered right now. You cannot make async operations on here! Of course the canvas will be disposed, it only lives for one frame. The render method is called every frame and must be quick and short lived. When the image actually loads, you no longer will have access to canvas because the whole render cycle will be done. It was already rendered on the screen! You cannot change the past! That doesn't make sense.

What you need to do is to load the image elsewhere and render conditionally if it's loaded. Move the loading to your constructor:

```dart
        Flame.images.fromBase64('demo', imageBase).then((value) {
            this.image = value;
        });
```

And then on the render method, render conditionally:

```dart
    @override
    void render(Canvas c) {
        Rect myRect = const Offset(0.0, 0.0) & Size(size.width, size.height);
        if (this.image != null) {
            paintImage(canvas: c, rect: myRect, image: this.image);
        }
    }
```

By creating an image field on your component. Also consider using `SpriteComponent` instead that does all that for you in the correct way. And **never** make the render or update methods async ;)